# How can an answer have comments older than the answer?

Tags: support, bug

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95974/44517) shows me up as answered 11 hours ago, but the first comment was set 15 hours ago. How this can be?

[image: Here you can see what I'm talking about.]

Comment: GIF warning*&*&*#&@*

Comment: @Dronehinge: Sorry, what?

Comment: Because it is the scifi forum - time travel!

Comment: Show the answer was left at 02:31:30 and the first (oldest) comment was left at 15:26:56 on the same day.. so first comment was left about 13 hours after the answer. No bug/time-travel here.

Comment: @Dronehinge: I added a screenshot of it.

Comment: Hmm. that's not what I show, it says "answered yesterday" for me, not "answered 11 hours ago".

Comment: Have you refreshed the page? If you were on the page, left your computer and then came back, saw a "this post has new comments" and clicked it, it might do this. As far as I can see, the times are 16 hours ago for both answer and comment.

Comment: @Dronehinge: Hm strange, maybe some caching problem. But I already did `strg`+`F5` and it didnt change

Comment: @Catija: Ofc I did.

Comment: The screenshot is typical of having loaded the edit later on into the page after clicking on the *this post has been edited* banner, at which point the timestamp on it stops updating.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I can gurantee Thats not what I did.

Comment: Yet the comments on the post were not posted before the answer itself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As I allready said, I dont belive it is something else then a caching problem but I jsut wanted it to bring up.

Comment: But there is no such cache, not when you load the whole page.

Comment: The question is, what do you see "now" when you go there and refresh? Hover the times if necessary ("11 hours ago" etc) to see the full timestamp. What do you see *now*? Sincerely, this is impossible. I know bugs exist, but a bug causing the issue you report would "likely" affect many questions given the scripts in play here will be reused around the site(s). We'd have (likely) a lot of people reporting and discussing this issue.

Comment: No repro, probably some funky temporary glitch somewhere

Comment: Isn't reproducable for me anymore aswell.

Comment: @Zaibis "*Isn't reproducable for me anymore aswell*" Either site caching or your browser cache borking are the "likely" culprits.